# Can I seed what DHCP options are offered on my network connection WITHOUT server access

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server

When you get a DHCP address from a DHCP server it comes with options. I want to see all of the options set. Yes, I know that I could bug one of our extremely busy sysadmins and get them listed off to me by them, but I would rather just have them viewable through a program.

And I have seen this. It's just horribly time consuming and not very effective https://serverfault.com/questions/536309/can-i-see-dhcp-options-on-my-network-from-a-windows-client

Comment: http://www.ingmarverheij.com/read-dhcp-options-received-by-the-client/